# Magento2 how to associate attribute options to exist attribute?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I have created a **brand** attribute at admin end for product and associated to **default set.**

Now i have more than 300 options want to associate.

How to associate programmtically from csv/excel/text file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below methods to archive you goal.

readData will read csv file and convert it into array.

addBrandOption use brand array and add brand into brand option

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute $eavAttribute,
        ) 
{
        $this->_storeManager   = $storeManager;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
}

public function readData()
{
    $file = fopen("brand.csv", 'r');
    $all_rows = array();
    $header = null;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
        if ($header === null) {
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }
        $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    return $all_rows;
}


public function addBrandOption()
{
    $brandOptions = $this->readData();
    foreach ($brandOptions as $brandOption) {
        $languageValues = array();
        $languageValues[0] = $brandOption;
        $attr = $this->_eavAttribute->load(154); // add brand/manufacturer attribute is here 
        $option = []; 
        $option['value'][$languageValues[0]] = $languageValues; 
        $attr->addData(array('option' => $option));
        $attr->save();
    }
}
```

You can use below code on magento root.
Create php file on magento root and add this code.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

function readData()
{
    $file = fopen("brand.csv", 'r');
    $all_rows = array();
    $header = null;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
        if ($header === null) {
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }
        $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    return $all_rows;
}

function addBrandOption()
{
    $this->_eavAttribute = $obj->get('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute');
    $brandOptions = readData();
    foreach ($brandOptions as $brandOption) {
        $languageValues = array();
        $languageValues[0] = $brandOption;
        $attr = $this->_eavAttribute->load(154); // add brand/manufacturer attribute is here 
        $option = []; 
        $option['value'][$languageValues[0]] = $languageValues; 
        $attr->addData(array('option' => $option));
        $attr->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where we need to use this code ?

Comment: where we have to use this concept block, controller etcc ?

Comment: This is not a complete code this is concept you can use it any where. For your case you can use it on root folder

Comment: I have modified the answer above